# Test what happens when something clicked (jest)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am jest beginner on react, how to know when I should mock something? For example inside 'ListItem' I have 'click me' when that is clicked under that will come 'cameras' dropdown, so if I should check what happens when 'click me' is clicked or what it contains. I need to mock this or something else? At the moment with my code I am verifying component to be there.

```js
import {
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemText,
  ListItemSecondaryAction,
  Collapse,
  IconButton,
  MenuItem,
} from "@material-ui/core/";
export const SelectionList:

interface SelectionList {
  actionArgs?: string | undefined;
  onUpdateClick: (e: any) => void;
  onDeleteClick: (e: any) => void;
  onDetailsClick: (e: any) => void;
  action: string;
  name?: string;
  identifier?: string;
  classes: {
    button_basic: string;
    formControl: string;
    selectionCard: string;
  };
}

React.FC<SelectionList> = (
  props
) => {
  const itemListCollapseKey = props.action + "-itemlist-collapse";
  const [collapseStates, setCollapseStates] = useState({
    [itemListCollapseKey]: false,
  });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleExpandClick = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>,
    key: string
  ) => {
    setCollapseStates({
      ...collapseStates,
      [key]: !collapseStates[key],
    });
  };

  const listItems = (
    key: React.Key | null | undefined,
    content: SelectionList | undefined | string,
    element: SelectionList
  ) => {
    return (
      <MenuItem
        key={key}
        selected={isElementSelected(element)}
        button
        onClick={(event) => {
          selectElement(element);
        }}
      >
        <ListItemText primary={content} key={key + "-litext"}></ListItemText>
        <ListItemSecondaryAction
        // p={1}
        >
          <IconButton
            onClick={(e) => handleDetailsClick(e, element)}
            aria-label="details"
          >
          </IconButton>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </MenuItem>
    );
  };

  

  let childList: React.ReactElement | string = "";
  if (data && data.length > 0) {
    childList = (
      <Collapse
        key={itemListCollapseKey}
        in={collapseStates[itemListCollapseKey]}
        unmountOnExit
      >
        {data.map((el) => (
          <List key={keyFromEl(el) + "sublist"}>
            {listItems(keyFromEl(el), el.name, el)}
          </List>
        ))}
      </Collapse>
    );
  }

  return (
    <List component="div" data-testid="SelectionListt">
      <ListItem
        key={props.action + "-header"}
        button
        onClick={(event) => {
          handleExpandClick(event, itemListCollapseKey);
        }}
      >
        click me
      </ListItem>

      {childList}
    </List>
  );
};
```

My testing:

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

function handleUpdateClick(event: any, type = "") {}
test("test", () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SelectionList
        classes={{ button_basic: "", formControl: "", selectionCard: "" }}
        action={"cameras"}
        actionArgs={""}
        onUpdateClick={handleUpdateClick}
        onDeleteClick={handleUpdateClick}
        onDetailsClick={handleUpdateClick}
      />
    </Provider>
  );
  const SelectionCardElement = screen.getByTestId("SelectionListt");
  expect(SelectionCardElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: any suggestion/help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you view components as separate testable units. So that when you're testing `ListItem` - you test all `ListItem` functionality. Then when you test your `SelectionList` - you mock `ListItem` component and only test all `SelectionList` functionality.

Then you will test how these two components integrate with each other by creating integration tests that don't focus on implementation, but rather what's being rendered on the page, what user can actually see.

**UPDATE**

What I mean is (in pseudo-code):

```js
// ListItem.spec.jsx
it.todo("list item renders");
it("list item triggers click callback when clicked", () => {
  const onClickCallback = jest.fn();
  const elem = render(<ListItem onClick={onClickCallback} />);
  elem.click();
  expect(onClickCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

and

```js
// SelectionList
it.todo("selection list renders");
```

As for how you mock, the simplest way would be to do something like this:

```js
<SelectionList listItemComponent={ListItem} />
```

or

```js
<SelectionList listItemComponent={<ListItem props="bla"/>} />
```

etc.

Comment: could you give working example of my code? How shoud <ListItem> be mocked ? to know what happens when its clicked

Comment: see update, please

Comment: could you possibly add all which are needed in code, so it can be copy paste and try ? for example <Provider store={store}></Provider> ? what is "listItemComponent" what should be instead of it ?

Comment: it's a new prop that you can add, and sorry I can't provide full solution

Comment: could you show how to add listItemComponent, now i am getting 'Property 'listItemComponent' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<SelectionList, never>'.ts(2322)'

Comment: also getting : TypeError: elem.click is not a function

Comment: no, sorry, I can't explain all the basics, I only suggested high-level stuff. cheers!